# haproxy not passing X_FORWARD_FOR on HTTP POST

Tags: php, haproxy

I've setup HAProxy with the

```
option forwardfor
```

option so it'll pass on the user's IP to PHP via $_SERVER[ "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" ].

If the page request isn't a POST it's populated fine but if it is then it won't be populated.  Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Thanks everyone!

My whole HAProxy conf file for reference:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
    #log loghost    local0 info
    maxconn 4096
    #chroot /usr/share/haproxy
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    #debug
    #quiet

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    maxconn 4096
    contimeout  5000
    clitimeout  50000
    srvtimeout  50000

listen webfarm :80
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server webA 192.168.240.4 weight 1 maxconn 2048 check
    server webB 192.168.240.3 weight 1 maxconn 2048 check

listen smtp :25
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    balance roundrobin

    server smtp 192.168.240.4:25 check
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the HAProxy Manual:

> It is important to note that as long
>   as HAProxy does not support keep-alive
>   connections, only the first request of
>   a connection will receive the header. 
>   For this reason, it is important to
>   ensure that "option httpclose" is set 
>   when using this option.
>
> Examples :
>       # Public HTTP address also used by stunnel on the same machine
>       frontend www
>           mode http
>           option forwardfor except 127.0.0.1  # stunnel already adds the header
>
> ```
> # Those servers want the IP Address in X-Client
> backend www
>     mode http
>     option forwardfor header X-Client
> ```
>
> See also : "option httpclose"

So you can try the httpclose option, but I would try it after hours or in test in case of a performance penalty?

Comment: Hey Kyle, you're spot on, that fixed it.